# Ember-data is sending html format instead of when using in mobile (phonegap)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm testing ember+ember-data form my mobile app. I'm using the 1.0 and 1.0.0.beta2 versions. When i'm making a simple find

`App.__container__.lookup('store:main').find('admin_users')`

ember is setting a request format to html instead of json. I've tried with basic $.get and i have a json request with no problems. It only happens in ember data...

Comment: Can you show how you are running the ajax call using jquery? Url, params etc.

Comment: $.get('http://'+BACKEND_HOST+'/api/users/'+showId+'.json', function(data){
   users = data['users']
})

Comment: it is a backend that i use for a web app in that is also in ember.js

Comment: Are you setting the `namespace` and `host` property of DS.RESTAdapter? See `ENDPOINT PATH CUSTOMIZATION` section in that link http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html

Comment: Yes i have them both set. In rails i see the request ````Started GET "/api/artist_profiles" for 192.168.0.17 at 2013-09-13 15:27:50 +0200
Processing by Api::ArtistProfilesController#index as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 1ms

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):````

Comment: it seems to be CORS related however i have set up the CORS in my application controller...

Comment: I use a Steroids which encapsulate phongap and i think it might be comming from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this solved my problem

```
DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  headers: { 
    "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript; q=0.01"
  } 
});
```